# Can not receive real-time readings from BLE device on iOS device

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, ios-bluetooth

I have a BLE device which I want to receive Real-Time readings from. I managed to get the stored ones using.

```
currentDevice.Peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: notifyingCharacteristic)
```

Then I get the stored readings in `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)`

After all stored readings are read, the `didUpdateValueFor` function stops getting called. How can I get real feeds?

Comment: That depends on the device. It may need some configuration to send real time readings. You would need to refer to its documentation

Comment: Okay, Thank you =)